# Flutter navigation inside showModalBottomSheet conflicts with isScrollControlled

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-layout, navigator

I'm trying to build a bottom Dialog with a separate navigator in it for an onboarding flow.
The dialog should have an auto height (mostly bigger than the default 50%) so I enabled `isScrollControlled`. However when I put in a `Navigator` in the `showModalBottomSheet` builder it creates a full height page by default.

```dart
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    ),
  ),
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Navigator(
        initialRoute: OnboardingPage.route().toString(),
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          final path = routeSettings.name;
          if (path == '/onboardingpage') {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: routeSettings,
              builder: (_) => OnboardingPage(),
            );
          }

          return new MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: routeSettings,
            builder: (_) => OnboardingPage(),
          );
        },
      ),
  },
),
```

`OnboardingPage` is a StatelessWidget of

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Text("Welcome to this example onboarding"),
    Text("subtitle"),
  ],
);
```

The navigator is needed because the Dialog should have multiple pages where the user can navigate between. It's possible to set the height property but I want a dynamic height and a navigator at the same time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your on boarding screen has a Scaffold, remove it as you wont need it. And in your boarding screen, wrap your column in a container, and give it a dynamic height, using MediaQuery.

```
Contaner(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50, //50% of the screen.
 child:
   Column(
    children:[
```

Comment: It's not the `OnboardingPage ` which adds the height, it is the `Navigator`. So I could always wrap the Navigator in a sized widget, but the goal is to have the height based off the widget height.

Comment: What if you gave the sized box a dynamic height based on mediaQuery?

Comment: That's indeed possible, however I'm still curious how the Navigator expands the height in the first place and if it's possible to work around that. To make it really work like an auto height.

Comment: what if you pass the `context` here `builder: (context) => OnboardingPage()` to tell the widget to behave according the context of it's parent? Have you tried that?